# How to measure the impact of a promotion on the sales?

Tags: time-series, measurement, marketing

I would like to measure the impact of a promotional campain on the sales evoltion.
The problem I am facing is the seasonality of the sales; let me expalin I have a very seasonal sales evolution initially (before the campain) these a big diffrece between the sales in the winter and in the summer.

Ideally i would evaluate the sales within 2 years one before and one after the campain to eliminate the seasonal effect. However there was already 2 other campains after the first one within a 4 months period between each one.

How can I measure the impact while taking into consideration the seasonality of the sales?

Thanks.